# Implement autoencoder with attention layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to modify the autoencoder model so I can add an attention layer on the "bottleneck/compressed" layer.

Suppose i have 2 encode Density layers, the attention layer i want to add, and 2 decode Density layers.
How can I develop this architecture in tensorflow?